# Can i execute using V8 engine from Javascript to execute a C or C++ or JNI functions with Flash user interface?

Tags: java, c++, c, flash, actionscript-2

Can i have my javascript which is getting executed via Flash gui button to trigger backend application layer written with either C, C++ or Java?

Example: My operating system is Flash full screen. Button on press it use javascript and execute local system built in functions and give interactive response.

Thank you

Comment: What does the V8 engine have to do with this?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: V8 engine is the thought to bridge with C++ functions. But Flash user interface will need action to reach console. How can flash reach a java or c or c++ functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to have your back-end Java code exposed through a Java Web application. The JavaScript can invoke the Web application (ex. through Ajax) which in-turn will delegate the call to your Java code.

Comment: Think about fast development. GUI design need to be done fast and quick (Qml, etc) so Flash user interface is used. Now i need fast realtime click button actions with backend. Ajax is slow process, i need to have object speed or socket speed but socket is not secured. Java web application will slow down development speed. My method i need to know actually.